# How do I know whether an active PostgreSQL query is still "working"?

Tags: r, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am appending a large data frame (20 million rows) from `R` to `PostgreSQL` (9.5) using `caroline::dbWriteTable2`. I can see that this operation has created an active query, with waiting flag `f` using:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'dbname'
```

The query has been running for a long time (more than an hour) and I am wondering whether is is stalled. In my Windows 7 Resource Monitor I can see that the PostgreSQL server process is using CPU, but it is not listed in Disk Activity.

What other things can I do to check that the query has not been stalled for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if the backend is using CPU time, it is not stalled. SQL queries can run for a very long time.

There is no comfortable way to determine what a working PostgreSQL backend is currently doing; you can use something like `strace` on Linux to monitor the system calls issued or `gdb` to get a stack trace. If you know your way around the PostgreSQL source, and you know the plan of the active query, you can then guess what it is doing.

My advice is to take a look at the query plan (`EXAMINE`) and look if there are some expensive operations (high cost). That may cause the long execution time.